# document scroll doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Neither this script:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    alert("works");
})
```

nor this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    alert("works");
})
```

works in IE 8 and earlier.
I don't know why, could somebody help?

Comment: Any errors in left bottom corner of IE window?

Comment: I use IETester and I don't see any error.

Comment: Try in online test tool like [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/start)

Comment: I reached the limit but is it possible to test scroll there? Doesn't it do only screenshots?

Comment: @user3145385 Which version of JQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/rQGT4/show) and check it in [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/start#os=Windows&os_version=7&browser=IE&browser_version=8.0&zoom_to_fit=true&url=http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/rQGT4/show&resolution=1024x768&speed=1):

- IE8 - window scroll works
- IE7 - window scroll works

Check what you don't have javascript errors on page.

Answer (score 0):

**Mainly three things you should see**

1.If you have given style as

```
overflow:hidden
```

2.If you have given height in page **percentage.**

3.if you have given `float:static`.

Fix this issue your IE 8 problem will be solved.

**Reason :**

IE 8 is different than nything else for CBC check IE frist! To the topic, IE 8 hides (only scrolling bar) of scroll bar if you have overflow as hidden, secoundly if you have places hight as 100% IE 8 takes overflow as hidden (can say takes by its own!) n float is element who can go beyond page size if you have it as inherit or relative but static dose not increase dynamicly.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I check each and this is not the problem.